# Get the value of the attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the value of the attribute.I have tried to grab the alt attribute by

`jQuery('#galleryalbum img').attr('alt');`

but I cant get the value

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // jQuery('#galleryalbum img').each(function(){
    title = jQuery('#galleryalbum img').attr('alt');
    console.log(title);
    //});    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="galleryalbum" style="height: 100px; width: auto; position: relative;">
  <div id="1" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: absolute; width: 429px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
    <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/intranet/sites/default/files/styles/gallery_image/public/Vidhya%20R%20-%20Hi5.jpg?itok=LCNjfrSm" width="700" height="300" alt="" title="Vidhya R - As you look back with pride and a sense of achievement... Here's wishing you many more years of success and joy at Aspire! Happy 5!"
      style="width: 100%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You code seems to work , but you `alt=""` is empty so thats why it dont write anything in `console.log()`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working right but your `alt` is empty.

```js
alert($('img').attr('alt'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OA0z.jpg?s=64&g=1" alt="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML alt is empty and I believe you are expecting to see what is in the title. 
If you give some content in the alt ="some content here" you will have the result in the console. 
If you want to see the text in the title attribute, then use

```
 jQuery(function() {
       jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       // jQuery('#galleryalbum img').each(function(){
             title = jQuery('#galleryalbum img').attr('title');
             console.log(title);
       // });    
       });
    });
```